# how to get data from selected row from datagridview

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

i have a new problem, I have a datagridview, try to see the picture, I want when cells that exist in the datagridview on click, then click on the data entered into textbox1,
anyone know how where how?
thanks for helping me

[image]

I was tried like below, but its not work

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellContentClick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellContentClick
        If Me.DataGridView1.RowCount > 0 Then

            TextBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(Me.DataGridView1.SelectedRows)


            'TextBox1.Text = Me.DataGridView1.Rows(Me.DataGridView1.row).Cells(1).Value
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: You need to supply what you have tried. This is not too difficult, so if you haven't tried anything I really think you should.

Comment: yeah , i have tried, but, i didn't find solution, you can't see code above,

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To get the cell value, you need to read it directly from `DataGridView1` using `e.RowIndex` and `e.ColumnIndex` properties.

Eg:

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellContentClick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellContentClick
   Dim value As Object = DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Value

   If IsDBNull(value) Then 
      TextBox1.Text = "" ' blank if dbnull values
   Else
      TextBox1.Text = CType(value, String)
   End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue and this works excellently.

```
Private Sub DataGridView17_CellFormatting(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs) Handles DataGridView17.CellFormatting  
  'Display complete contents in tooltip even though column display cuts off part of it.   
  DataGridView17.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).ToolTipText = DataGridView17.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Value 
End Sub
```